# mongoose getting Model validation failed instead of custom error message

Tags: mongoose

I'm sure the issue is with the password validator because if I comment it out the document gets inserted. Also if I enter a valid password everything works. Here is my entire UserSchema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        match: /.+\@.+\..+/
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
        set: urlModifier
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        validate: [
          function(password) {
            return password.length >= 6;
          },
        'Password should be longer'
    ]
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['admin', 'owner', 'user']
    }
});
```

This issue I'm having is that instead of my custom error message I get

```
ValidationError: User validation failed
<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\lotus\Desktop\mastering_mean\application\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1162:32)
    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\lotus\Desktop\mastering_mean\application\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1037:16
        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at validate (C:\Users\lotus\Desktop\mastering_mean\application\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:651:7)
            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\lotus\Desktop\mastering_mean\application\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:679:9
                <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Array.forEach (native)
                    <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\Users\lotus\Desktop\mastering_mean\application\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:656:19)
                        <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\lotus\Desktop\mastering_mean\application\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1035:9
                            <br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Mongoose version is ^4.05

Not sure if this is a bug, something changed in the API, or something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No mention of this in the particular tutorial I'm learning from.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

The custom error message is available in the validation error object returned to the save(err) function in the controller as err.

Basic

user.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
            return next(err);
        } else {
            res.json(user);
        }
    });

Will return the default error message "User validation failed"

This

```
user.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err.errors.password.message);
            return next(err);
        } else {
            res.json(user);
        }
    });
```

Will return the custom error message